# I can't install any libraries, it gives me an error saying subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

```
PS D:\Learning\py\python basics\> pip install numpy  
Collecting numpy
Downloading numpy-1.26.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.6/15.6 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [37 lines of output]
Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
Downloading ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
-------------------------------------- 132.4/132.4 kB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
    
        [13 lines of output]
        C:\Users\Abaan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nxqms1f9\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\Abaan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nxqms1f9\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\Abaan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nxqms1f9\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\Abaan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nxqms1f9\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\Abaan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nxqms1f9\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version      
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
    
        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]
    
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried upgrading pip, setuptools but it still gives error
It doesn't allow me to do install any libraries, and gives me same error

I have also checked my system's environment variables, but everything seems to be in order.
I even tried running the installation as an administrator, but the issue persists.
Upon researching online, some users suggested checking the system's PATH variable, which didn't yield any conclusive results.
I have verified that my internet connection is stable and not causing any interruptions during the installation process.
I attempted to install the package in a new virtual environment, but the same error appeared.
The error seems to be related to the CMake installation, but my CMake executable is already properly configured.
There haven't been any recent system updates or changes that could have triggered this issue.
I'm considering reaching out to the package maintainers for further assistance.

My Pip version: 23.2.1
My Python version: 3.10.12

Comment: have you tried re-installing cmake?

Comment: Today, it worked for me using `py -m pip install numpy` on **Python 3.12.0rc3**

Comment: the method mentioned above might work. What happens when you just run "python" in the terminal. or "python -m pip install numpy". Is python on path? have you tried a newer version of python?

Comment: I would recommend following three steps (not sure if you did)
`pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install numpy`

Comment: why is this tagged "opencv"? it has got nothing to do with OpenCV.

Comment: @Raky. note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.  OP already downloading.

Comment: Latest is Python 3.10.13 **released Aug. 24, 2023**. https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Ok. I am Looking `git archive did not support describe output`. Is there a `git` command in there somewhere? Maybe that `git` command is not supported. Maybe. Best Case Scenario would be reinstall `python` and maybe the latest version recommended by toyota Supra

Answer (score 1):

try to setup the full python version

```
$ sudo apt install python3-full
```

Comment: Do we know that the OP is on a distro that provides this package or uses apt at all? (If they didn't provide enough information to know if an answer applies, it's better to add a comment instead).

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks @Oleksandr Minenko